# How to allocate unequal probability?

Tags: gams-math

I want to allocate the probability of 1000 scenarios. (|S|=1000). And I don't want all these possibilities to be considered equal. (not to be; P(s)=0.001 for all s).
How can I allocate an unequal probability? I mean we have:

sum(s,p(s))=1 and for all s,s': s<>s' ; we don't have p(s)=p(s').

Do we have a specific command for this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that probabilities in your problem are known parameters. Then, it is a matter of populating the p(s) parameter, not a specific command. You can load the desired probability values from an external file.